# flickity.js play/pause video based on current cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I am using [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) to create a slider of images and videos. When changing slides, I want to play the video on the current slide (which has a class of .is-selected), and then pause again once I move to the next slide.

The code below manages to find any videos within the slider, but plays them on any slide change, rather than specifically for the slide they are within. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
// Init Flickity
var $carousel = $('.carousel');

$carousel.flickity();

// On slide change
$carousel.on('change.flickity', function() {           
    // Find videos
    var currentSlide = $(this).find('.is-selected');
    var video = $(this).find('video');

    // Play videos
    video[0].play();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is pause all videos on every slide change and only play the one on the selected slide. I did something similar (without jQuery):

```
var carousel = document.querySelector(".carousel");
var flkty = new Flickity(carousel, {
// ..
});

flkty.on("change", function() {
  console.log("Flickity active slide: " + flkty.selectedIndex);

  flkty.cells.forEach(function(cell, i) {
    if (cell.element == flkty.selectedElement) {
      // play video if active slide contains one
      // use <video playsinline ..> in your html to assure it works on ios devices
      var video = cell.element.querySelector("video");
      if (video) {
        console.log("playing video " + i);
        video.play();
      }
      return;
    }

    // pause all other videos
    var video = cell.element.querySelector("video");
    if (video) {
      console.log("pausing video " + i);
      video.pause();
    }
  });
});
```

As I stated in the comment, you might wanna use the "playsinline" attribute for your videos, otherwise you'll run into problems on iOS.

Also: using the "settle" event instead of "change" allows you to start playing once the active slide settled at its end position.